# DataTables Data Manager (CRUD) Add-on for Google App Engine

Tags: jquery, google-app-engine, datatables

I found [DataTables Data Manager (CRUD) Add-on](http://jquery-datatables-editable.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/index.html) by Google. I wonder if this add-on can work with Google App Engine (python) because my site is developed by GAE.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://jquery-datatables-editable.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/inline-edit.html):

> You will need page that handles update AJAX requests (UpdateData.php
>   in this example) and accepts following parameters:
>
> 1. value - contains new text value of the cell that user edited
> 2. id - id of the updated record (id is placed in the tag that
>      surrounds the cell)
> 3. columnId - position of the column of the cell that has been edited
>      (hidden columns are counted also)
> 4. columnPosition - position of the column of the cell that has been
>      edited (hidden columns are not counted)
> 5. rowId - id of the row containing the cell that has been edited
>
> If operation was successfully completed server-side page should return
>   value that user entered during editing. Otherwise, it should return
>   error message.

This means that you will need to write your own interface that will process the updates, as well as populate the data in the table. This is a jQuery plug and is completely on the client side. Server side can be anything, including a python application running on GAE.

Comment: really? Thanks. But it will be hard for me to write my own interface since I am just a beginer:D

Comment: Take a stab at it and post up your code - that's how you learn :)

Comment: which one should I use? http://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-editable/ OR http://www.jtable.org/ OR http://www.jeasyui.com if my site is built on GAE?